# Multiple set to macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm trying to build an advanced system of reporting and logging, and I have a problem.

Example:

work.check_true is empty.

When this table is empty then variable like 'czy_wyslac' should have value 2.
If this table not empty, variable 'czy_wyslac' should have value from field "gen" (1 or 0) from table work.check_true.
Next step - depending on the value of variable 'czy_wyslac" processing one from three step to next macro. I do not have a problem with this.

Below is my code:

```
data _null_;
call symput('obscnt',0);
set work.Check_true;
call symput('obscnt',_n_);
stop;
run;

%macro get_table_size();
%global czy_wyslac;
%If &obscnt=0 %then call SYMPUTX('czy_wyslac',2);

%else
    proc sql noprint;
    select
        gen into: czy_wyslac
    from work.Check_true
    ;quit;
%mend;


%macro Create_log_mail();

   %if &czy_wyslac. = 1 %then
    %do;
        data work.maile;
        zal = "T:\XXX\XXX\Risk\XXXX\XXXX\OUTPUT\Results_of_compare &calosc..xlsx";
        run;

        options emailsys=XXemail host=XXXemailport=XXX;

        FILENAME mail EMAIL;

        DATA _NULL_;
        SET WORK.maile END=eof;
        FILE mail ENCODING='UTF-8';
        PUT '!EM_TO! "XXXXX@XXXXXX"';
        PUT 'Szanowni,';
        PUT 'Załącznik zawiera znalezione różnice między szablonem kalkulatora a zawartym w systemie ATP.';
        PUT 'Wpis _TYPE> = PLIK - baza porównywana';
        PUT 'Wpis _TYPE> = ATP - rekord wyciągnięty z ATP';
        PUT;
        PUT 'Baza zawiera również wynik porównania wyposażenia oraz baseline.';
        PUT;
        PUT 'Pozdrawiam,';
        PUT 'KJ SYSTEM REPORT';
        PUT '!EM_FROM! XXXSYSTEM REPORT <noreply@XXXXX.pl>';
        PUT '!EM_SENDER! XXXXSYSTEM REPORT <noreply@XXXX.pl>';
        PUT '!EM_BCC! ';
        PUT '!EM_SUBJECT! XXXXXXXX';
        PUT '!EM_ATTACH!' zal;
        PUT '!EM_REPLYTO! Please do not reply for this mail - regards :)';
        PUT '!EM_SEND!' / '!EM_NEWMSG!';
        IF eof THEN PUT '!EM_ABORT!';
        RUN;

            proc sql;
            Create table LOG_CREATE as
            Select
            distinct
            date()*86400 format datetime20. as EXTRACT_DATE,
            date()*86400 format datetime20. as REFERENCE_DATE,
            'MAIL: Results_of_compare' as STAGE_NAME,
            '99_02_MAIL_RESULT' as PROCES_NAME,
            '02_CALCULATOR_ATP' as SCHEMA_NAME,
            20 as etap_no,
            'SENT' as STATUS,
            &Count_records_02. as records,
            'Wysłano mail' as Comments,
            . as alert_records,
            '' as Alert_comments,
            &_timer_start format datetime20. as START_PROCESS,
            datetime() format datetime20. as END_PROCESS,
            datetime() - &_timer_start format time13.2 as Duration
            FROM work._PRODSAVAIL
            ;quit;
    %end;

    %else %if &czy_wyslac. = 0 %then %do;
        proc sql;
        Create table LOG_CREATE as
        Select
        distinct
        date()*86400 format datetime20. as EXTRACT_DATE,
        date()*86400 format datetime20. as REFERENCE_DATE,
        'MAIL: Results_of_compare' as STAGE_NAME,
        '99_02_MAIL_RESULT' as PROCES_NAME,
        '02_CALCULATOR_ATP' as SCHEMA_NAME,
        20 as etap_no,
        'NOT SENT' as STATUS,
        . as records,
        '' as Comments,
        . as alert_records,
        '' as Alert_comments,
        &_timer_start format datetime20. as START_PROCESS,
        datetime() format datetime20. as END_PROCESS,
        datetime() - &_timer_start format time13.2 as Duration
        FROM work._PRODSAVAIL
        ;quit;
    %end;
%mend;
%Create_log_mail();
```

Comment: Thank for your amendments. My english still is poor...

Comment: I may be missing it, but do you actually state anywhere what the 'problem' actually is and what's not happening or is happening? There's an answer but it seems to be an assumption since we can't run your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `work.check` is empty, the `select gen into :czy_wyslac from work.check_true` will not return anything, thereby retaining any previous value in `&CZY_WYSLAC`.

Therefore the below will accomplish what you want :

```
%LET CZY_WYSLAC = 2 ; /* default value */
proc sql noprint ;
  select gen into :CZY_WYSLAC from work.check_true ;
quit ;
```